# how do call this function in my frontend dapp using metamask and ethers js

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, smart-contract-wallets, web3-providers

I have this smart contract function and I am trying to call it from my frontend dapp but cant seem to figure out how to do so using ethers js and metamask.

```
 function multiSendFixedEth(address payable[] memory recipients, uint256 amount,string memory description) public payable {
    
    require(recipients.length > 0," Please input an Address ");
    require(amount > 0, " Amount Must Be Greater Than 0 ");
    require(Owner == msg.sender, " You are not authorised to call this function ");
    
    uint256 length = recipients.length;
    
    for(uint256 i=0;i<length;i++) {
        recipients[i].transfer(amount);
        addresses.push(recipients[i]); 
    }

    numOfAddy = addresses.length;

    transactions.push(Transaction(msg.sender, numOfAddy , amount , description, block.timestamp));

    emit Transfer(msg.sender, numOfAddy , amount , block.timestamp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate web3 on your front end code, and then search for the deployment address of your contract, and decode the resultant ABI to utilise the encoded functions. Read through [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-web3-frontend)